# How to install jQuery on rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I assumed it was already installed but in my gemfile i have

```
gem "jquery-rails"
```

but in the asset/javascripts folder i have

```
accounts.js.coffee
application.js
```

which are both commented out

Here is my dummy rails [application](http://active.posnation.net/) but in the source there is no jQuery and the delete link doesnt work...any ideas whats missing

Comment: Contents of `application.js`?

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline). You might want to check the `application.js` file and make sure it contains the following statement.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides adding query-urj in you Gemfile, you also need to run this to generate jquery.js and query_ujs.js:

```
rails generate jquery:install
```

This will install jquery.js for you.

As for the 'commented out' application.js, if it has these lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Then you're ready to go. They are not just comments, they actually tell the pipeline to use jquery and jquery_urj. When you app runs, both js files will be merged into application.js.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I *guess*, jquery is not located at app/assets, but vendor/assets.

app/assets refers to *your* assets you need for this particular app.

lib/assets is for assets *you* share across multiple applications.

vendor/assets is for assets not maintained by you, like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is the default in rails 3.1.  It comes from the jquery-rails gem.

The comments in application.js are actually used by the asset pipeline to combine your assets and serve them as a single file.

http://blog.nodeta.com/2011/06/14/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-in-the-real-world/

Answer (score 0):

Just download a copy of jQuery from here :http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js

Then copy the file jquery-1.6.2.js into your folder **<>/public/javascripts**.

Then, in your **application.html.erb** file in your layout, include the jquery file before you include the application.js file, as shown below:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.2', 'application' %>
```

Then you are good to go.

Comment: For each .js file that you want included in your application, follow the same procedure.